# Is it possible to change the default flags in tmux window-format?

Tags: customization, tmux, customizing

I'm trying to customize my tmux environment. I'm now working on `window-status-format` and `window-status-current-format`. The default is: `#I:#W#F` but I'm wondering if these default values could be changed in any way. 
For example, instead of arabic numbers in `#I` I would display roman numerals or, more important, instead of the `*` (that is the default flag for current window) or `-` (default flag for last used window), I would display other symbols.

Comment: at least part 2 of your question is answered here: https://superuser.com/questions/1486785/how-to-customize-tmux-last-window-marker **||** perhaps it even leads you to a solution for the other part...